# AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler' неизвестная ошибка

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot

client = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    client.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет!')

client.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Ошибка:

```
@client.message_handler(commands=['start'])
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'
```

Раньше делал бота, все было нормально, переустановил виндовс и пошла эта ошибка. Переустанавливал VS, менял версии пайтон, ничего не помогает.

Comment: Вероятно, вы не ту библиотеку поставили: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69512683/8324991

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!!!!